# Is there a way to have a list type object in Django models?

Tags: python, django, database

I'm starting my first solo Django project and have run into how to store things on my database. What I'm doing is trying to create a web-based grocery store. I'm wanting to add an order model where I can store a user and then a list or optimally a dictionary of what they want. I know the dictionary may be a stretch, but is there some way to create a model list? I've looked at similar questions and seen the JSON option I'm not really sure how I can make that work since I can't manipulate that in the admin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a `Foreign Key` model field.

In your scenario, you probably want to keep track of the Grocery Inventory. So you might have a model like this:

```py
class GroceryItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500) # Green Apples
    inventory = models.IntegerField() # 300
```

This will keep a record of all items that you can list for sale or that is available.

Now what you are looking for is a User to have many different items that they want or want to have in a cart. So you can create a model like this:

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) #This is how we let our database know that a user can only be holding 1 cart.
```

Now there are many ways you can implement this type of strategies, some having there strengths and weaknesses, but one way is to create a new model that connects the both of them.

```py
class GroceryCartItem(models.Model):
    grocery_item = models.ForeignKey(GroceryItem) # This means that this object can only be part of 1 grocery item, but grocery item can be part of many
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
```

With the example above, we can create a new object instance that connects both the user's cart and the grocery cart item.

So if I wanted to run a query on my shopping cart, it could be something like:

```py
GroceryCartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart_belonging_to_user)
```

And it would return with all of the items.

Database relationships can be complicated but is arguably what makes them so powerful. To learn more about it, I would recommend reading up on relationships here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/relational-databases-defining-relationships-between-database-tables/ or in the django docs.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! This really helped and thanks for the link I took a brief look through it and it seems like really good content definitely going to dig through it more soon. I'd give you an upvote but my account is brand new.